# Drag a view and scroll if view exceeded the current height visible on screen

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview

Say I have a scrollView and a few views inside it. I dragged one of the views down vertically,  and I wanted the scrollView to scroll automatically up to make the view visible while dragging at the same time.

I had an algorithm in mind which is to get the y position of scrollView which is visible without scrolling and check if the view which is being dragged exceed this y position and if it exceeds, execute the method to scroll the scrollView up.

However, I do not know how to get the y position of scrollView which is visible. There is no issue with dragging. The only problem I faced was to scroll the scrollView up.

Kindly advice on what can be done. Thanks.

Comment: tried using (void)scrollRectToVisible:(CGRect)rect animated:(BOOL)animated but it was not working as well

Answer (score 0):

Hey for those who need help in this, I used the current scrollview content offset + self.view.size.height to get the visible y position of scrollview. Check current dragged y position of the UIView against this y position of scrollview. If exceed, scrollview content offset += UIView.height